# Replacable placeholders in properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have a properties file in which I'd like to amend certain properties to include a user ID (and possibly other runtime loaded values), something like the following...

```
emailer.queuename=Emailer.${user}
```

...so that the property value might become, in this example, `Emailer.SMITHJ` when read in.

I thought of extending the `Properties` class and overriding the `getProperty method`, but I also need to ensure that Spring will modify properties accordingly when using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for the context (I see I can override `convertPropertyValue` in this class).

But is there neat a way that I achieve both?

Thanks

==================================

UPDATE:

The simple solution in *my* case I have discovered, is just to use the system property (e.g. ${user.name}) and since the `systemPropertiesMode` for the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class is set to `fallback` Spring will sort it automatically. However, I will still need to create an inherited class for the cases where I use the properties file directly, or just inject the value into the class it is used in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to replace some properties in property files before they are used to resolve properties in bean configurations.

As you have said, bean properties are resolved by `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. To perform upfront processing you will also need a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and implement the `Ordered` interface to specify when it will run.

Alternatively if you register your `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s programatically, they will be executed in the order registered and before any other bean's registered through other means.